# gdal_calc to replace null values of one raster with values of another not working

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, raster-calculator

I have a  raster containing `NULL` values in which I'd like filled

To do so, I have interpolated the raster via IDW in GDAL, and then used the QGIS raster calculator to perform the following calculation

```
(Original = 0) * Interpolated + (Original != 0) * Original
```

Basically, where there are data values of `0` in the original raster, replace them with the interpolated values. But if the the original rasters data values are anything other than `0` then keep the original value.

This runs perfectly in QGIS with no complaints and creates my new raster. So I decided to try it in GDAL using `gdal_calc`

```
gdal_calc -A original.tif -B interpolated.tif --outfile newraster.tif --calc="(-a = 0) * -b + (-a != 0) * -a"
```

However, I keep getting the error `Error! Dimensions of file interpolated.tif (4138, 4902) are different from other files (7347, 8705).  Cannot proceed`

Even with adding the `--extent=ignore` flag it wont work

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html

> Note that all files must have the same dimensions (unless extent
> option is used), but no projection checking is performed (unless
> projectionCheck option is used).

and

> --extent= New in version 3.3.
>
> This option determines how to handle rasters with different extents.
> This option is mutually exclusive with the projwin option, which is
> used for providing a custom extent.
>
> For all the options below the pixel size (resolution) and SRS (Spatial
> Reference System) of all the input rasters must be the same.
>
> ignore (default) - only the dimensions of the rasters are compared. if
> the dimensions do not agree the operation will fail.
>
> fail - the dimensions and the extent (bounds) of the rasters must
> agree, otherwise the operation will fail.
>
> union - the extent (bounds) of the output will be the minimal
> rectangle that contains all the input extents.
>
> intersect - the extent (bounds) of the output will be the maximal
> rectangle that is contained in all the input extents.

So the option `--extent ignore` is the default behavior and because 4138, 4902 is not equal to 7347, 8705 then gdal_calc will not run.

What options you have depends on the coordinate system and pixel size of your original files. Could you add that info into your question?